# Ошибка при попытке получить количество элементов

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await

В чем проблема ? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Мне нужно получить количество элементов из таблицы, использую WebDriverIO, вот ссылка на $$, с помощью которого, как написано, и получают все элементы https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$/

```
public async getMlvTableRows(id: string): Promise<WebdriverIO.ElementArray> {
  return (await $$(mlvTable + id + mlvTableRow));
 }
```

Получаю такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция должна вернуть элемент, который в себе содержит все остальные элементы, которые находятся в нем, в данном случае это таблица. Дальше получаю длину вот так

```
public async getMlvTableSize(id: string): Promise<number> {
  return (await this.getMlvTableRows(id)).length;
 }
```

Comment: примеры из справки работают?

Comment: да, из вставки работают